# Pylons application Internationalization

Tags: python, internationalization, pylons

What the best way to make pylons application internationalist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=pylons+i18n) finds [these docs](http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonsdocs/Internationalization+and+Localization).

Comment: you recommend to use standart tools?

Comment: Absolutely. That way other Pylons developers will easily understand what you're doing, instead of first having to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

PyICU and I highly recommend Babel.
Also if you need SEO you should read this:
http://my.opera.com/WebApplications/blog/2008/03/17/search-engine-friendly

If want more info (you can start using babel in five minutes), read the pylons book its free:
http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1/internationalization-and-localization.html