# How the url internationalization should be made?

Tags: python, url, internationalization, routes, pylons

I have a question regarding the internationalization of a website's URL addresses.

*The question is how to make it properly?*

What I would like to do is something like this.

Assume you have an **URL** in your address bar

`www.mydomain.com/en/book`

then if you type `www.mydomain.com/de/book` you will be redirected to a german version of a site so the url will change to `www.mydomain.com/de/buch` and so on.

*Idea*:

I thought about making a table that would be used as a dictionary between different languages. For the website content I would still use **i18n**, but I think that for **urls** it cannot be applied.

*The implementation*:

I thought about modifying **routing.py** in a way that before any connection is invoked I would recognize in the URL a language that user wants, and store it in a session variable for later use with **i18n**. Then I would redirect user to a correct url for this lanugage and invoke a poper **controller/action**.

Any ideas, suggestions or recomendations are welcome.

Edit (2011-04-04 18:35):

1. I have just reminded myself that I have already encountered a similar problem on [Opera Blog](http://my.opera.com/WebApplications/blog/2008/03/17/search-engine-friendly);
2. there is a problem on StackOverflow: [Pylons application Internationalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341387/pylons-application-internationalization), but it deals solely on site internationalization, no problem with **URLs** included;
3. **WZeberaFFS** has pointed our a small issue that may arise if no **reference** or **previous language settings** are taken into account;
4. **Additional question**: What should be stored in database, to make it work fast? I have my own idea, but I will give it a try later on.

Comment: Why do the urls need to be translated?

Comment: Why not? To give you a reason: I thought it would be a good SEO practice, as every link/url will always work, and will work with proper word and language. So, there will be no situation like `/de/book`, which would make no sense. Moreover, I thought it would be a nice feature. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I believe your implementation will work as log as you don't have the same name of to different pages like if you have a page called `www.mydomain.com/en/music` and if `music` in German is `book`, then the problem will be that if you want to go to `www.mydomain.com/fr/music` then you don't know if you are coming form `/de/` or `/en/`. But this is only a problem if you have colliding names on different pages cross languish it will still work if you have the same name for a word in 2 different languish you wont really know where they cam form but you will know where they are heading.

If you have that problem then you have to save a session or hope that the client sends a referral.

Comment: Good point (upvote). Although, it is not very probable it will happen. However, as you have mentioned I will have to check the session variable **or** reference.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how it could be done in Python, but usually people do such things through some kind of URL Re-writer or URL filter - something that will consume your URL and re-direct to proper page setting Locale at the same time.